# CSS font rendering (box model size) different in Edge vs. Webkit vs. Firefox

Tags: css

I'm building a single page of text that's a tight fit onto a sheet of paper. For some unknown reason, Edge renders everything larger.
I'm using border-box, null margins and padding. I've tried CSS reset but the result is the same.

In the attached example, the H1 element is 57.03x25px in Chrome, 64.7x25.35px in Edge. H2 is 57.031x16px in Chrome, 64.7x16.09px in Edge.
I assume Chrome is right since I've specifically set a font size of 25px and 16px respectively.

All these small sub-pixel errors creep up until I get quite a significant difference after a page of text. Width increase does not bother me so much, but I assume it to be related.

I can't find any other option or margin to reset, so I assume that Edge/IE somehow adds undocumented white space.

Edit: Firefox also renders larger, 27px text height for a font of 25px.

https://jsfiddle.net/m74b0s09/

```
<style>
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    /*font: 12pt "Tahoma";*/
    font: 10.66px "Tahoma"; /* IE/Edge does not render as Chrome with pt units, seems to ignore sub-pixel sizes */
    z-index: 0;
  }

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .section {
    margin-top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .section h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }

  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 9pt;
  }

  body {
    font: 10.66px "Tahoma";
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .header {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .header h1 {
    border: none;
    text-transform: none;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  .header .name {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .header .contact {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
  }

</style>

<body>
<div class="section header">
  <div class="name">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>

    <h2>Ipsum</h2>

  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <h3>
      H3 text
    </h3>

    <h3>more H3</h3>

    <h3>even more H3</h3>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I managed to work around the issue by manually specifying line-height in addition to font-size. This ensures that everything stays almost pixel-perfect across browsers, but it's a lot of tedious work.

Comment: `that's a lot of tedious work` :: welcome to handling multiple platforms and multiple different technologies to get the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CSS Normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which is a pack of CSS rules to make the main browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards.